# Is ROS.org's Code API generator supposed to work with python code imported using git_checkout.mk

Tags: ros, rosdoc, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using git_chekout.mk in http://www.ros.org/wiki/teer to fetch teer's source code into ROS. Currently, there is no "Code API" generated for it; is it because the generator is busy/overloaded or because it is not supposed to index fetched code? If the latter explanation is the right one, what is the best practice to document inside ROS code fetched from outside (be it with git_checkout, svn_checkout or tarball's import)?

Thank you, kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28308/is-ros.org%27s-code-api-generator-supposed-to-work-with-python-code-imported-using-git_checkout.mk/) by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The indexer does not 'build' any code that it runs the generator against (see NOTE).  git_checkout.mk requires building the code.  In the past, we attempted to add this feature to the indexer, but it simply is intractable for it to successfully build arbitrary code checkouts, for numerous reasons.

If you wish to document fetched code, then the way to do that is to submit the fetched code separately to the indexer, or manually generate the documentation yourself and upload to an appropriate location.

NOTE: The only exception is documentation for diamondback/electric versioned docs, which is only for released/debian-ized stacks.  This feature is going away as, starting in Fuerte, stacks are no longer including source within the installed layout.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1